# Java ArrayList.remove()

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to remove word **"a"** from `t1` object. Why `t2` object also got affected?

**Code:**

```
package newproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NewProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        String str[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.addAll(Arrays.asList(str));

        Test t1 = new Test(words);
        Test t2 = new Test(words);

        System.out.println("Result Before ");
        System.out.println("T1 " + t1.getWords());
        System.out.println("T2 " + t2.getWords());

        // Only T1 remove words, not T2
        t1.removeWords("a");

        System.out.println("Result After ");
        System.out.println("T1 " + t1.getWords());
        System.out.println("T2 " + t2.getWords());
    }   

}

class Test {
    private ArrayList<String> words;

    Test(ArrayList<String> words){
        setWords(words);
    }

    void setWords(ArrayList<String> words){
        this.words = words;
    }

    ArrayList <String> getWords() {
        return this.words;
    }

    void removeWords(String word) {
        this.words.remove(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Why t2 object also got affected."*  Because `t1` and `t2` are sharing the same array list.

Comment: Let's assume you and your partner share a car and your partner uses all the gas in the tank. Is your car now empty as well? Of course, it's the same care. The same happens here, both `Test` instances work on the same ArrayList.

Comment: Is it because the ArrayList words is pass by reference, not by copy/value? I though each object will make a copy of ArrayList words

Comment: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40480)

Answer (score 0):

Because both t1 and t2 share the same `ArrayList`. Instead of passing the `ArrayList` in to the constructor you want the constructor to say `this.words = new ArrayList<String>();` to ensure that every instance of `Test` has it's own collection.

Comment: Thank you.How can I modify the code to make it work? I am still trying to understand.
I try adding this.words = new ArrayList<String>(); into the constructor, but the result is still the same

Comment: Is it because the ArrayList words is pass by reference, not by copy/value? I though each object will make a copy of ArrayList words

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in setWords method. You can modify your setWords method to initialize a new Object of ArrayList rather than initializing your data member *"words"* to new Object in a constructor.

```
    void setWords(ArrayList<String> words){
        this.words = words;
    }
```

In the above snippet, your datamember *this.words* is assigned the reference of your parameter *"words"* (which was initialized in main) with new keyword. Both t1 and t2 will point to same reference. Instead change the method to

```
 void setWords(ArrayList<String> words){
            this.words = new ArrayList<>(words);
        }
```

This way a new ArrayList if created and assigned to your class object. Another way to overcome your problem if to do the following.

```
void setWords(ArrayList<String> words){
    this.words = new ArrayList();
    for(String s: words) {
        this.words.add(s);
    }
}
```

The point is everytime you create a class object, a new ArrayList must be created and assigned to your data member "words".

Answer (score 0):

Simply because, both `t1` and `t2` access the same list. (The passing value is the same, which is `words` that you create and pass into constructors)

You may either pass two new Lists to the constructor.

```
Test t1 = new Test(new ArrayList(words));
Test t2 = new Test(new ArrayList(words));
```

Or You can create a new List inside the constructor

`this.words = new ArrayList(words);`